# Confusion on sessioncookie in our custom session timeout

Tags: php, session

I have read the following tutorial: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

But is it necessary to set `session.cookie_lifetime` to 0? If necessary, when should we set it ?

I do not want to spoil that useful tutorial by asking question there.

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to set the expiration as an expiry date in seconds (UTC format), not a timespan from current time, so use

```
time()+(60*30)
```

for expiry date parameter. time function outputs current time in seconds, and you are adding seconds to it
if you set it to 0 cookie will expire when client closes his browser

Comment: So this should be done during user successfully logins or on each page is loaded? Using [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) before outputting any HTML ?